# Windows desktop support in Cordova

Tags: windows, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am into analyzing the best possible solution for one of my new development assignment. 
My requirements:
 - Platforms supported: Android, iOS, Windows Mobile, Windows desktop.
 - Need a single code base as far as possible.

I have worked on a couple of apps using Cordova/Ionic/Angular that supports iOS and Android.
However, I am not very sure about Windows support, desktop in particular.

Can experts here help me out with,
 - is Windows desktop supported by Cordova
 - if yes, which versions of Windows are supported (I have a requirement for supporting Windows 7 as well. is that possible?)

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can make use of the browser platform in cordova so that it can be deployed as a web application which can be accessed in desktops.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean that way it can be used a desktop application? how will the plugins behave? for e.g. I have to use camera plugin or say a plugin that manages Bluetooth or WiFi connectivity

Comment: All the plugins may not work. But some of them work. Bluetooth and wifi, you may have to extend the plugin based on need.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova windows create UWP apps, those are apps that can only be distributed through the windows App store (App Store is available on Windows 8 and newer).

There is a [cordova-win7](https://github.com/fabriceds/cordova-win7) platform, that should create regular windows apps, but it's unmaintained

For desktop apps most people use [electron](https://electron.atom.io/), but Cordova plugins are not compatible

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is inclining me to keep the code base for Windows separate.

Comment: one quick question,, can the UWP apps be distributed privately (without app store)

Comment: Looks like it's possible, but never tried, see the "Sideload your app on previous versions of Windows" section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Answer (score 0):

you can try with crosswalk.it is the best solution for best web runtime for your mobile and desktop web applications.

here you can find the windows platform tutorial.
 [crosswalk windows](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/windows.html)